# python web scraping IP blocked

Tags: python, web-scraping, request-headers

I am trying to extract the source code of the html page. It was working fine before. but now the source web server wanted more evidence that I am NOT a bot. This is the error: your IP is blocked. My IP is NOT blocked for sure as I can still open the page manually via any browser. Do I need to change any parameters before making the request. Thanks.

```
headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.77 Safari/537.36"}
req = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
url_content = req.content
url_content = url_content.replace(b'data-imgid', b'\ndata-imgid')
output_file = open('downloaded.txt', 'wb')
output_file.write(url_content)
output_file.close()
```

Comment: You could try using a different user agent perhaps. What I'd recommend is to use a scraping library such as beautiful soup.

Comment: Try to use exactly the same headers as your browser use. If your IP is indeed blocked, consider using a proxy service.

Comment: isnt beautiful soup used to parse the downloaded content and NOT to download the content...correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: NO my IP is NOT blocked. I can still open via browser...and I can still get the content via wget...just the python doesnt work and I am sure it has something to do with header

Comment: Like i mentioned this is NOT IP issue being blocked. It is the python. I was able to extract the content using PHP/bash/java/C# but NOT using Python.